# Introducing another axis in 2D vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I was reading linear dependence between vectors, where I come across below explanation:

---

In a rectangular xy-coordinate system every vector in the plane can be expressed in
exactly one way as a linear combination of the standard unit vectors. For example, the
only way to express the vector (3, 2) as a linear combination of i = (1, 0) and j = (0, 1)
is

> (3, 2) = 3(1, 0) + 2(0, 1) = 3i + 2j  ...formula(1)

Suppose, however, that we were to introduce a third coordinate axis that makes an angle of 45◦ with the x-axis. The unit vector along the w-axis is

> w = $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Whereas Formula (1) shows the only way to express the vector (3, 2) as a linear combination of i and j, there are infinitely many ways to express this vector as a linear combination of i, j, and w. Three possibilities are

(3, 2) = 3(1, 0) + 2(0, 1) + 0$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ = 3i + 2j + 0w

(3, 2) = 2(1, 0) + (0, 1) + $\sqrt{2}$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ = 3i + j + $\sqrt{2}$w

(3, 2) = 4(1, 0) + 3(0, 1) - $\sqrt{2}$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ = 4i + 3j - $\sqrt{2}$w

---

What I did not understood is

- How these last three expressions of (3,2) are formed, I just did not get anything of it. Maybe missing something elementary maths.
- How introducing another axis allows us to express any vector in **infinitely many ways**?, and how these last three expressions proves that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (mostly) just basic vector arithmetic.

In the explanation of linear dependence, $(1,0)$ represents a particular vector of two components, while $(0,1)$ represents another such vector.

When we write $3(1,0),$ that again is a vector obtained by multiplying the vector
$(1,0)$ by the scalar $3.$ The result is
$$3(1,0) = (3,0).$$
Likewise,
$$2(0,1) = (0,2).$$
We can add two vectors componentwise, like so:
$$(3,0) + (0,2) = (3+0, 0+2) = (3,2).$$
In fact we can add three (or more) vectors, for example
$$(2,0) + (0,1) + (1,1) = (2+0+1, 0+1+1) = (3,2).$$
Vector subtraction also works componentwise:
$$(4,3) - (1,1) = (4-1, 3-1) = (3,2).$$

Finally, the three vector calculations at the end of the explanation you copied do not
*prove* that the number of ways to represent $(3,2)$ as a linear combination
of the three given vectors is infinite.
They merely prove that there are *at least three* representations.

So the explanation you copied makes a broad statement without proof. That is a possible
point of confusion.

A more general way to represent $(3,2)$ is
$$(3,2) = (3-r)(1,0) + (2-r)(0,1) + (r\sqrt2)\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right).$$
This formula is true for any real number $r,$ and each different real number
gives us a different linear combination of the three vectors.
Since there is one distinct linear combination for every real number,
and there are an infinite number of real numbers, there are an infinite number
of distinct linear combinations of the three vectors in order to produce $(3,2).$

The three examples shown in the explanation you copied
were just the applications of this formula for $r=0,$ $r=1,$ and $r=-1.$

Comment: damn am so stupid

Comment: Maybe the other explanation just didn't "click" for you. It somehow set you up to expect one thing and delivered something different.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Because i and j form a basis for the plane you can express any vector in the plane as a *unique* combination, so that $(3,2) = 3i + 2j$ ( you are probably OK with this part.)

(2) the vector $w$ can also be expressed as a unique combination of $i$ and $j$, $w = i/\sqrt(2) + j /\sqrt(2)$

(3) so, $w - i/\sqrt(2) - j /\sqrt(2) = 0$, i.e. the "zero vector" (0, 0).

(4) we can add any number of zeroes to the vector (3, 2) and still have (3, 2), so that

- $(3, 2) + (0, 0) = (3, 2)$
- $ (3, 2) + [w - i/\sqrt(2) - j /\sqrt(2)] = (3, 2)$
- $ (3, 2) - \sqrt(2) [w - i/\sqrt(2) - j /\sqrt(2)] = (3, 2) - \sqrt(2) w +(1, 0) + (0, 1) = (4, 3) - \sqrt(2) w = (3, 2)$
- $ (3, 2) + \sqrt(2) [w - i/\sqrt(2) - j /\sqrt(2)] = (3, 2) + \sqrt(2) w -(1, 0) - (0, 1) = (2, 1) + \sqrt(2) w = (3, 2)$ 
  (there's a typo in your answer for this one).